# Strapi missing "Files Upload" section in admin panel?

Tags: strapi

I set up a new install of strapi with postgres as the db and am now trying to hook an s3 bucket for file uploads for when I deploy to heroku.

Am I missing something? Why am I not seeing a `Files Upload` option in my UI? (Screenshot below was taken from https://medium.com/@tamirp/strapi-%EF%B8%8Fmlab-%EF%B8%8Fheroku-%EF%B8%8F-s3-step-by-step-deployment-for-a-non-developer-1cae3ec3dfe0 tutorial regarding the part about adding your credentials to strapi and the version for that tutorial says 3.0.0)

I ran `npm i strapi-provider-upload-aws-s3` but I can't even get to the part where you select that after you install it.

[image]

[image]

package.json

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "A Strapi application",
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "strapi develop",
    "start": "strapi start",
    "build": "strapi build",
    "strapi": "strapi"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "knex": "<0.20.0",
    "pg": "^8.3.0",
    "strapi": "3.0.6",
    "strapi-admin": "3.0.6",
    "strapi-connector-bookshelf": "3.0.6",
    "strapi-plugin-content-manager": "3.0.6",
    "strapi-plugin-content-type-builder": "3.0.6",
    "strapi-plugin-email": "3.0.6",
    "strapi-plugin-upload": "^3.0.6",
    "strapi-plugin-users-permissions": "3.0.6",
    "strapi-provider-upload-aws-s3": "^3.0.6",
    "strapi-utils": "3.0.6"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "A Strapi developer"
  },
  "strapi": {
    "uuid": "471592c9-a46f-4c41-b503-664f047e482b"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.0.0",
    "npm": ">=6.0.0"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the instructions are not 100% clear in my opinion but if you just manually create `/extensions/upload/config/settings.json` file/folders with your correct S3 bucket information and restart your server.

Then when you upload a file to the strapi media library it will automatically upload it to your s3 bucket! Cool!

```
{
  "provider": "aws-s3",
  "providerOptions": {
    "accessKeyId": "dev-key",
    "secretAccessKey": "dev-secret",
    "region": "aws-region",
    "params": {
      "Bucket": "my-bucket"
    }
  }
}
```